# What does "following by" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does "following by" mean?
In this particular case, there is a sentence:

> "Name the file with your last name following by title of the image."

Which one of these phrases should be used as the name of the file?

1. LastnameTitle
2. TitleLastname

Comment: It sounds like a mistake to me.  *Following by* doesn't make any sense.  I suspect they meant *followed by* (which would make it LastnameTitle), but you would have to ask the author to be sure.

Comment: @stangdon Thank you very much, I am grateful for your opinion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your instruction should be correct to be

> Name the file with your last name followed by title of the image.

and would heave the syntax

> LastnameTitle